# Tracking a users progress during a test/form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, coldfusion

I have a form/test with 20 fields that users fill out. The user chooses a course, then enters their personal info along with what test they want to take. After that they then answer 20 true and false questions and submits the answers. ColdFusion then calculates the score and stores the score and user information in the database.

The problem I am facing is that due to poor user input we are missing data. The users are not submitting the test and then they wonder why it is not in the report. I need to come up with a solution that will track the users progress and logs it. I don't need it to be detailed I am just looking to see if they attempted to take the test or not. My solution is to have a table in the database with two boolean columns. One will be True when the user enters and then the other will be true when they exit. This will record if a user has entered the form without submitting it properly. This will then identify that the reporting errors are in fact user errors.

I can't seem to think of any other way to do this and wanted others inputs of how they will handle this task.

Comment: How about having a single boolean field indicating entered test data status , default will be false however if user inputs values then you can toggle it to true . In case you are persisting the test data entered by user why not look for it in the table and state the user about incomplete form submission next time he demands it ?

Comment: If your users are too dumb to know how to submit a form on a website, maybe they ought not have their test scores recorded. :D

Comment: The sad thing is these guys are doctors.

Comment: If that many users are failing to submit the form, maybe the form is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to completely track and get as much info as possible I decided to use AJAX to submit each answer the user inputs into the database. This will allow me to not only see where the disconnect is but give back more detailed reports all around. Having user answers will show me what questions are being answered wrong the most as well.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is to use AJAX or jQuery.

On every click in an input box, update a counter. (You may use the keypress() method)
http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

When the user leaves the input box, check if field is empty. If yes, then keep counter updated. If not, just decrement the counter.

Send the final counter value to be used as you wish.